# omitting 'def' in Groovy declarations

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, it appears that the following declarations are both legal

```
private final results = []
private final def results = []
```

Is there any difference between these two?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [Groovy: what’s the purpose of “def” in “def x = 0” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184002/groovy-whats-the-purpose-of-def-in-def-x-0)

Comment: @Leonel: Great! My next question is.. .what is the "variable script bindings"?