# Gradle def vs ext

Tags: gradle

What is the difference between using `ext.varname` and `def varname`. E.g. the following code seems to work the same:

```
task copyLicenses {
    def outDir = project.buildDir.absolutePath + '/reports/license/'

    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'licenses'
            into outDir
            include '*'
        }
```

seems to work exactly the same as

```
task copyLicenses {
    ext.outDir = project.buildDir.absolutePath + '/reports/license/'

    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'licenses'
            into outDir
            include '*'
        }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Keyword `def` comes from Groovy and means that variable has [local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184002/groovy-whats-the-purpose-of-def-in-def-x-0) scope.

Using `ext.outDir` means that you add property `outDir` to [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html), think of it like project has a map of properties with name `ext`, and you put your property in this map for later access.