# Gradle grouping dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I was experimenting with my project's build.gradle. Currently my project consist of several modules, each of these module have common dependencies, such as android support or network library. I'm [Experimenting with gradle dependencies](http://alexfu.github.io/android/2017/11/07/experimenting-with-gradle-dependencies.html). 
I've declared a group of dependencies named *lib_mandatory()* in file *lib-group.gradle*, but when I tried to include it in my app's build.gradle the gradle sync failed.

```
Error:Could not find method lib_mandatory() for arguments [] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

How can I fix this? or any hints about what this error means?

Update:
Here's the lib-group.gradle

```
def dependencyGroup(Closure closure) {
   closure.delegate = dependencies
   return closure
}
def lib_mandatory = dependencyGroup{
   implementation libraries.rxjava
   implementation libraries.rxandroid
}
```

and here's the app's build.gradle

```
apply from: '../lib-group.gradle'
dependencies {
    lib_mandatory()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide how you defined that method in your *lib-group.gradle* and how you call it to *app.gradle*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that is used in that article is a bit different, the article used the function inside the `lib-group.gradle` and only `applied` (apply from ...) the `lib-group.gradle` in the app's `build.gradle`.

In your approach, you're trying to use the function in the app's `build.gradle`.

If you want your functions to be accessed from other files, you should use `ext` instead of `def`. You might want to read this:
[Gradle def vs ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186108/gradle-def-vs-ext)