# How to use environment variables in a groovy function using a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use environment variables defined outside any node in a Jenkinsfile.  I can bring them in scope on any pipeline step in any node but not inside of a function.  The only solution I can think of for now is to pass them in as parameters.  But I would like to reference the env variables directly inside the function so I don't have to pass so many parameters in.  Here is my code.  How can I get the function to output the correct value of `BRANCH_TEST`?

```
def BRANCH_TEST = "master"

node {
    deploy()
}

def deploy(){
    echo BRANCH_TEST
}
```

Jenkins console output:

```
[Pipeline]
[Pipeline] echo
null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create and access the global variables in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solutions are

1. Use `@Field` annotation
2. Remove def from declaration.  See [Ted's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185879/6020034) for an explanation on using def.

Solution 1 (using `@Field`)

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def BRANCH_TEST = "master"

   node {
       deploy()
   }

   def deploy(){
       echo BRANCH_TEST
   }
```

Solution 2 (removing def)

```
BRANCH_TEST = "master"

   node {
       deploy()
   }

   def deploy(){
       echo BRANCH_TEST
   }
```

Explanation is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/P7VMQQuMdsY/bHfBDSn9GgAJ),

also answered in this SO question:
[How do I create and access the global variables in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305910/how-do-i-create-and-access-the-global-variables-in-groovy)

Comment: You need to remove duplicate `import` statement in the answer.

Comment: Why should removing the def solve the issue? Could you explain a bit what the issue is and how your solution works?