# How do I define a global variable in a scripted jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, cloudbees

I would like to define a global variable in a Jenkins Scripted Pipeline that can be accessed anywhere in the pipeline. i.e. any stage, and any method.
If I define the var at the top of the pipeline, it is works in the `node` declration, and in the `stage` declaration, but not in a called method.
I don't want to use the env.XXX and withEnv([]) because I may have to call these methods from various different places, and that means using env sometimes, and not others.

Here is my simple JenkinsFile I use for a scripted pipeline:

```
def jenkinsNode = 'linux'
def DEBUG = 1

node(jenkinsNode){
  echo ">> node($jenkinsNode)"
  echo "DEBUG = $DEBUG"

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }

  stage('test-this') {
    if (DEBUG) {
      echo "DEBUG is On"}
    else {
      echo "DEBUG is Off"
    }

    testMethod()
  }
  echo "<< node($jenkinsNode)"
}

def testMethod() {
  echo ">> testMethod()"

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }

  echo "<< testMethod()"
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
Running on rh6-a01 in /jenkins_home/jenkins-rh6-a01/a98289de/workspace/test/test/test-global
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
>> node(linux)
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG = 1
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG is On
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test-this)
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG is Off
[Pipeline] echo
>> testMethod()
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DEBUG for class: WorkflowScript
[...snip...]
```

How can I code this Jenkinsfile that will allow any method to access the DEBUG variable?

Comment: Globals are usually defined outside the pipeline block. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063864/using-global-variables-in-jenkins-pipeline/54491768

Comment: Yes, your reference is to a Declarative Pipeline.  My query is specifically for Scripted Pipelines.

Comment: Apologies you are correct. You just need to remove the def.  See full answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Removing the `def` from the declaration at the top resolves this.

```
def jenkinsNode = 'linux'
DEBUG = 1

node(jenkinsNode){
  echo ">> node($jenkinsNode)"
  echo "DEBUG = $DEBUG"

  if (DEBUG) {
 .....
```

Gives the output

```
>> node(linux)
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG = 1
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG is On
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test-this)
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG is On
[Pipeline] echo
>> testMethod()
[Pipeline] echo
DEBUG is On
[Pipeline] echo
<< testMethod()
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
<< node(docker)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This is because using `def` binds the variable to the current scope (which the method contents are not in).  Not using `def` doesn't bind the scope allowing it to be used anywhere in the script.

Do note thought that Groovy WONT stop you using the variable with `def` elsewhere which could cause unintended results e.g. adding a `def DEBUG = 0` in the method

```
def testMethod() {
  echo ">> testMethod()"
  def DEBUG = 0

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }
```

Would still run fine but would turn off DEBUG in that method.

Comment: Not a good practice. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571316/strange-variable-scoping-behavior-in-jenkinsfile

Comment: Fair, using `field` is likely safer. But it think you would need a massively complex script for it to be an issue. In over 8 years of Jenkins. I’ve never hit an issue with it for the simplicity it provides.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the variable as an argument

```
......

    testMethod(DEBUG)
  }
  echo "<< node($jenkinsNode)"
}

def testMethod(DEBUG) {
  echo ">> testMethod()"

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }

  echo "<< testMethod()"
}
```

2. If the above solution is not something you are looking for, using the `@Field` annotation will work as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37425799/10697591

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def DEBUG = 1
def jenkinsNode = 'master'


node(jenkinsNode){
  echo ">> node($jenkinsNode)"
  echo "DEBUG = $DEBUG"

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }

  stage('test-this') {
    if (DEBUG) {
      echo "DEBUG is On"}
    else {
      echo "DEBUG is Off"
    }

    testMethod()
  }
  echo "<< node($jenkinsNode)"
}

def testMethod() {
  echo ">> testMethod()"

  if (DEBUG) {
    echo "DEBUG is On"}
  else {
    echo "DEBUG is Off"
  }

  echo "<< testMethod()"
}
```