# Jenkins Groovy - overwriting global variable in definition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem with overwriting an existing global variable value within a definition. A simple example piece of a jenkinsfile:

```
my_var = 0

def my_def() {
  my_var = 1
}

node {
  stage 'test'
  my_def()
  echo my_var
}
```

The output of echo is 0 and I'd like it to be 1.
I read this post: [Groovy: what's the purpose of "def" in "def x = 0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184002/groovy-whats-the-purpose-of-def-in-def-x-0/185879#185879) but I couldn't make it work.
I couldn't find any explanations of how to return a value from such a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to use transform. Off the top of my head, that would look like:

```
@groovy.transform.Field int my_var = 0

def my_def() {
  my_var = 1
}

node {
  stage 'test'
  my_def()
  echo my_var
}
```

Comment: Great, it worked for me. Thx!
`@groovy.transform.Field int my_var = 0

def my_def() {
  my_var = 1
}

node {
  stage 'test'
  my_def()
  echo "OUTPUT: "+my_var
}`