# Global methods in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185879/982238) if you define a variable without `def` it becomes "global" and thus you can access it from anywhere in the script. How can I do this with a method (as there is no definition without `def` AFAIK)?

For the record: I'm defining Jenkins pipelines and want to access some "global" methods outside from various stages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define any method in your `Jenkinsfile` outside `pipeline {}`, e.g.

```
@NonCPS
def pomVersion() {
    def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'
    return matcher ? matcher[1][1] : null
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "sed -i.bak -e 's|\${appVersion}|'${pomVersion()}'|g' dep_pom.xml"            
                sh 'mvn clean -U install -DdeploymentContext=test -f dep_pom.xml'
            }
            post {
                success {
                    junit '**/target/**/*.xml'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some exemplary script that defines `pomVersion()` method that reads version from `pom.xml` file. It can be accessed in any stage and any step of the pipeline.

Regarding your statement that:

> if you define a variable without def it becomes "global" and thus you can access it from anywhere in the script

it's not like that actually. Groovy script is compiled to a class that extends [`groovy.lang.Script`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) class. It uses `bindings` structure (think of it as a `Map<String,Object>`) that stores all variables used in the script. This mechanism allows e.g. to share same bindings between two separate scripts if they are run using same `GroovyShell` instance.

Comment: Your `pomVersion` should probably be marked with `@NonCPS` as [`java.util.regex.Matcher` is not `Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of doing this would be to use the [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) feature within Jenkins to define additional methods in a separate file. This is detailed in a [blog and talk by Brent Laster](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/06/27/speaker-blog-SAS-jenkins-world/).

Comment: This is true. But imagine that I just have one method which is project specific and simplifies deployment. Does it make sense to create a shared library just for that?

Comment: If it's going to just be the one, probably not. I can't quite recall, but does Jenkins have support for Groovy Closures within the sandbox yet?