# What is differences between either of using def and without using def in Jenkinsfile in script block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have two Jenkinsfile for sample:
The content of A_Jenkinsfile is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("first") {
            steps {
                script {
                 foo = "bar"
                }
            sh "echo ${foo}"
            }
        }
        stage("two") {
            steps {
            sh "echo ${foo}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other one is B_Jenkinsfile and its content is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("first") {
            steps {
                script {
                 def foo = "bar"
                }
            sh "echo ${foo}"
            }
        }
        stage("two") {
            steps {
            sh "echo ${foo}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I build them, B_Jenkinsfile is failed and A_Jenkinsfile is success.

What is differences between either of using def and without using def in Jenkinsfile in script block?

Comment: I don't know, Why users gave negative score to this question!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two types of Pipeline syntax. `Declarative Pipeline` and `Scripted Pipeline`. A declarative pipeline starts with a `pipeline {}` wrapper and will have `Stages` and `Steps`. Declarative pipeline limits what is available to the user with a more strict and pre-defined structure. Where in scripted Pipeline it's more closer to groovy, and users will have more flexibility on what they can do.  When you run something in a `Script` block in a declarative Pipeline, The script step takes a block of the `Scripted Pipeline` and executes that in the Declarative Pipeline. Basically, it runs a `Groovy` script for you. So your question can be rephrased as what `def` means in a Groovy script.

Simply in a Groovy script, if you omit adding the `def` keyword the variable will be added to the current script's binding. So it will be considered as a Global variable. If you use `def` the variable will be scoped, and you will only be able to use it in the current script block. There are multiple detailed answers for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184002/groovy-whats-the-purpose-of-def-in-def-x-0?answertab=scoredesc), so I'm not going to repeat them.